# How to stop a function call if its take more than 3 secs in Object c

Tags: objective-c, function, call, blocking

i have a function it will take 3 to 30 secs time for execution depends on some calculations.

i want to stop if my function call takes more than 5 secs.
how to do this in Objective C.

Answer (score 2):

You have to execute command in a separate thread (with performSelectorInBackground or with NSThread, for example), wait for 5 seconds (again, with unix sleep or NSThread methods) and then (depending on what is being done in the execution thread):

- set some field in a class to "terminate", and check this field often in a "long" function
- cancel IO operation, if there is a block
- cancel a thread (you can read about it here: [how to stop nsthread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5193062/how-to-stop-nsthread))

Answer (score 0):

You can use a timer and put a condition like if the timer exceeds 5 seconds, do nothing.

Comment: Hi i am new to objective c , i tried with timer with 5 sec , but inside the "timerTick"function i called my function but my function execute after 30 sec then timer is not exit after 5 sec,  .can you please share a sample code.