# Cancelling sendAsynchronous request

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad, nsurlconnection, sendasynchronousrequest

I am using `sendAsynchronous` request to receive data from multiple request at same time. It works great, i am able to load all the data. Even it is faster. But i want to cancel my request if the user cancels the request. so i have created a `NSThread` and using that thread i have created asynchronous request. When user clicks cancel button i just cancelled the thread.

But even after cancelling the thread the data is still getting loaded. So i want to stop those requests completely from loading data.

Even i used this,

```
[NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:(id) selector:(selector) object:(id)]
```

but it doesn't work. Any help or suggestion will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html) the `NSUrlConnection` class has it's own `cancel` method.

Note: Why are you using `sendAsynchronousRequest` in a own thread? The completion-handler will be executed when the request returns. While the request tries to reach the server and get an answer the main-thread shouldn't be blocked. I suggest to use either a synchronous request in a background thread or an asynchronous request in your main thread. 
Also be aware, that your thread doesn't terminate just by calling [`[NSThread cancel]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5193062/how-to-stop-nsthread)

Comment: Ya i accept your answer, Even when i give asynchronous request in main thread i was not able to stop it. So can u give some example about canceling asynchronous request.